# Is there any way to split data in multiple tables?

Tags: postgresql, performance

I have one big table contain millions of record, is there any way to split data in multiple tables, and if yes then How and What is the best way to do it ?

As example,

I have table called : Master
Now is there way to split this table's data in tables called :  Master1, Master2, Master3,
Also if yes, How the application will work, how it will fetch data from particular table.

I use postgresql Database and javax.persistence API
Note that the reason behind doing this is to improve performance.

Can anyone help on this.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html

Comment: Yeah, you might want to look into partitioning.  You could just split the table into three parts, but if you need to query all data together logically, then it won't help your performance.

Comment: You may try to range partition the table. In any case before running queries do remember to execute `analyze` in postgresql.

Comment: I can do Partition anytime right ? I mean in live application's database.                    Just going through the link provided by @DanielE.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, So is there any other way to handle it (For performance purpose) ?

Comment: Yes, tune your table/query using indices.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. So index is the only best solution, is it ? Anything we can do beyond this (I mean add index and also do some-other stuff )

Comment: @DanielE.: please do not link to versions that are not maintained any more. Plus: in Postgres 10 partitioning was substantially improved (and will be even more in Postgres 11)

Comment: @ChandanRajput: "millions of rows" rarely require partitioning to begin with.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name for your suggestion and help.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry, i just put the comment as I don't have time to redact a full answer. I didn't check the version linked.